# Designing a lens

Tags: optics, lenses

What factors would I have to take into account when designing a lens.  For instance, I want to design a lens that has a focal length of approximately 20 cm, and it is intended to be used for wavelengths of approximately 560 nm.  I know that the material used for the lens is one factor, but are there others?  Also, does anyone have a recommendation for which material should be used?

Comment: There are alot of factors.  The material is a start.  But before, you want to know what the purpose, what constraints do you have in terms of size, and aberrations.  The list gets really long.  A common glass is NBK7

Comment: Lets assume I do not have any constraints.  I just want the lens to be used for humans so they can see the wavelength of 560 nm well.

Comment: Humans (who don't suffer from the most common form of colorblindness) can see the wavelength of 560nm "well" - it's the wavelength of green light. A lens can make us see smaller things or things that are further away better, but it can't change the eye's response to a certain wavelength.

Comment: The other question is why do you want to design such a lens, at all. You can buy plenty of 20cm focal length lenses from companies that make lenses and they will work just fine at 560nm. A simple lens with that spec (and no other requirement) can be had for a few dollars on the internet. OTOH, if you are trying to build an F0.8 telescope with 20cm focal length then you are probably in for years of R&D and millions of dollars in investment...

Answer (score 2):

If you "only" care about 560 nm, that makes life easier, since you don't have to worry about chromatic aberration. Other things to worry about:  What FOV? How much flatness of field? How much spherical aberration? How fast a lens do you need? You can only get a certain level of performance from a simple spherical lens, and if you get demanding you'll need to step up to multi-element lenses.

As for material, borosilicate (BK7) should do you just fine, and it's cheap.